# How to keep a hamburger menu icon to right side of toolbar in Ionic3

Tags: ionic3, hamburger-menu, ion-menu

I am trying below code to move icon to right side.

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side= "right">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <button ion-item (click)="openPage(homePage)">
          Home
        </button>
        <button ion-item (click)="openPage(friendsPage)">
          Friends
        </button>
        <button ion-item (click)="openPage(eventsPage)">
          Events
        </button>
        <button ion-item (click)="closeMenu()">
          Close Menu
        </button>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
```

But when i am trying with side= "right" , The list is coming from right side but hamburger menu icon is moving to right.
Is there any way to achieve this solution.Please help me if anyone is having the idea.

Comment: So the list is showing from right to left but the hamburger icon is still at top left corner ?

Answer (score 0):

To have the burger icon to the right you can try this :

```
<ion-toolbar no-border-top>
    <ion-title> Menu </ion-title>
    <button ion-button menuToggle right>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-toolbar>
```